# On Pokemon-GO My eggs have glitched

Tags: pokemon-go

We'll I have a 5 Kilometer egg and I've walked the distance 1 thing I can't hatch it i dont know what's wrong but someone please help I've tried tons but no it says 5/5Km

Answer (score 2):

The egg overview rounds kilometers to one lesser decimal place, so if you click directly onto the egg, you will see one more decimal place and you will see that you did not walked whole 5km.
(Yes it can be considered as a bug)

Overview:

```
5.0/5.0 km
```

Egg details after click:

```
4.96/5 km
```

Picture to demonstrate:
[image: Egg kilometers]